# Submit a form in or out a foreach

Tags: forms, jsp, foreach

I have a servlet webapplication with jsp related to some servlets, among them, I have this form:

```
<form action="MeetingDetails" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="mtgid" value="${selectMeeting.id}"/>
    <c:forEach items="${comments}" var="comment" varStatus="i">
    <p><input type="hidden" name="cmtid" value="${comment.getKey()}"/>
    <c:out value="${comment.getKey()}"/> - <c:out value="${comment.getValue()}"/>
    <input id="minus" type="submit" name="action" value="DeleteComment"/></p>
    </c:forEach>
    <p>New Comment: <input type="text" name="cmt" value=""> <input id="plus" type="submit" name="action" value="AddComment"/></p>
</form>
```

And when I send the action:Delete to the servlet, it recieves a wrong "cmtid" value, and if I put the form within the foreach, the parameter "mtgid" value is null...

Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Best advise on this kind of thing: Look at the HTML source in your browser before submitting and keep changing the code till it comes out as the HTML you expect.

Comment: Hi, i made all combinations that i could think of, but none of them work.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you expect to see in the end?

Comment: HTML looks fine, the problem is on the doPost on the server, when i get the request on the server after submiting this, the values aren't the ones i expect (which is, not null value for selectedMeeting.id, and the proper value for cmtid). if i put the foreach within the form, the cmtid makes no sense, and if i put the form within the foreach, selectedmeeting.id is null

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenient, I figured it out by:

```
                            <c:forEach items="${comments}" var="comment" varStatus="i">
                                <form action="MeetingDetails" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="mtgid" value="${selectMeeting.id}"/>
                                    <p><input type="hidden" name="cmtid" value="${comment.getKey()}"/>
                                    <c:out value="${comment.getKey()}"/> - <c:out value="${comment.getValue()}"/>
                                    <input id="minus" type="submit" name="action" value="DeleteComment"/></p>
                                </form>
                                </c:forEach>
                                <form action="MeetingDetails" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="mtgid" value="${selectMeeting.id}"/>
                                <p>New Comment: <input type="text" name="cmt" value=""> <input id="plus" type="submit" name="action" value="AddComment"/></p>
                                </form>
```

I was a little obfuscated and didn't see it